# Handle oncopy event after server's response

Tags: javascript, browser, websocket, oncopy

I want to modify the user's clipboard when he presses **CTRL+C** based on what the server responds. The communication with the server is done through a **web socket**.
I managed to get the oncopy event and I'm able to set some content to it, but only immediately. What I want is something like this:

- oncopy event fired and caught
- ask the server for something (socket.send(bla bla))
- receive answer from the server (socket.onmessage())
- update the user's clipboard by editing event.clipboardData

Is it possible?

Or is there a way in which I could do busy waiting in the event handling method while the message from the server is being received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, playing around with a clipboard is tricky business. What I have found out is that after a while the clipboard data are lost from the event object (might be a security meassure). So you either set the data immedietly or you loose the ability to set it.